# What SQL numeric data for non floating price?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having an issue on choosing the right numeric data for my price as my country currency do not use floating point.

Example: in my country currency we do not use this`- 12700.58-`

`example of our price: 127,000 (which is hundred twenty seven thousand)` for us.

So which sql numeric data type..i should use?

Thanks

Comment: You *NEVER* want to use floating point for currency values anyway.  [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) is a good choice.

Comment: what about `INT(12)`?

Comment: @Philipp what's int(12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all [`FLOAT/DOUBLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) are non-exact datatypes so you should avoid it. Better to use [`DECIMAL/NUMERIC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) because they are accurate datatypes.

In you example(only whole numbers) I would use simple `INT` to store price:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(price INT UNSIGNED);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (120000), (10);
```

The value with thousand separator `127,000` is only presentation matter and it should be done in application layer. If you still need to format it in database use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(price,0) AS formatted_price
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/569e7/2/0)**</kbd>